# integrating watson chatbot into facebook

Tags: spring-boot, integration, chatbot, watson-assistant

I want to integrate my chatbot in facebook messenger. I know watson assistant give us this feature but I'm developing a spring boot backend application that search for other answers if there is no response in watson assistant. and watson assistant display only watson responses. So, should I deploy my app on a server and generate my webhook url... Or this is workable with watson assistant. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Angham Elmabrouk 
You will find that this is a common task within Watson Assistant, although normally the application that Watson Assistant defers to if no answer has been encoded is Watson Discovery. Watson Discovery can digest web sites, documents etc, and then uses machine learning techniques to determine the best documents to return if Watson Assistant has no answer stored. Within Watson Assistant this is otherwise called a Search Skill. 
Even if you do not use Watson Discovery / Watson search skill the principles are the same, you just call out to your own Rest API. This happens within Watson Assistant, via the web hook process, and so does not get in the way of your Facebook integration.

Answer (score 0):

If answer is not found,create a node(Answer not found) then you can write a cloud function to call an external resource to fetch the information. You can pass the user input to your application and return the response to Watson Assistant.